# Custom form input with images does not display properly

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a custom form input that utilizes some images, it should look like this:
[image]

I've tried the following:

```
<style>
input {
    background-image: url(../img/search-background-middle.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    padding: 17px 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
}

form {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
</style>

<body>
<form>
    <img src="../img/search-background-left.png"/>
    <input type="text" value="   start typing to search..." size="40" maxlength="255"         />
    <img src="../img/search-background-right.png"/>
</form>
</body>
```

Which results in:

[image]

Why?? I'm not only interested in the solution, but also in the reason why this doesn't work. I think my understanding of inline elements put next to each other is flawed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the vertical-align to top

```
form * {vertical-align:top;}
```

also remove the spaces between the `img`s and the `input`

Answer (score 1):

1. remove whitespace between `img` and `input` elements (including linebreaks)
2. set height and line-height on `input` element to match the image height
3. set padding and margin to 0 on `input`.

Answer (score 1):

you may also need to add a float: left !important; to the input. Sometimes that fixes my issues when things aren't lining up